# Boost regex not replacing expression that replaces correctly on regex websites

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex, regex-greedy

I was trying to do a regex replace with boost::regex, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the regex expression:

```
(\\w+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+\tscript\t)(.+)(#)(.+)(\t\\d+(,\\d+)?(,\\d+)?,{)
```

And the formatter:

```
$1\"$2\"$3\"$4\"$5
```

The code: (getInput() returns a string with content that should match)

```
std::string &Preprocessor::preprocess()
{
    std::string &tempString = getInput();
    boost::regex scriptRegexFullName;
    const char *scriptRegexFullNameReplace = "$1\"$2\"$3\"$4\"$5";

    scriptRegexFullName.assign("(\\w+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+\tscript\t)(.+)(#)(.+)(\t\\d+(,\\d+)?(,\\d+)?,{)");

    tempString = boost::regex_replace(tempString, scriptRegexFullName, scriptRegexFullNameReplace, boost::match_default);

    return tempString;
}
```

When I put the following test cases on [this website](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/):

```
alberta,246,82,3    script  Marinheiro#bra2 100,{
brasilis,316,57,3   script  Marinheiro#bra1 100,{
brasilis,155,165,3  script  Orientação divina#bra1  858,{
```

The output of the website is correct:

```
alberta,246,82,3    script  "Marinheiro"#"bra2" 100,{
brasilis,316,57,3   script  "Marinheiro"#"bra1" 100,{
brasilis,155,165,3  script  "Orientação divina"#"bra1"  858,{
```

But with boost::regex the output is:

```
alberta,246,82,3    script  "Marinheiro#bra2    100,{
brasilis,316,57,3   script  Marinheiro#bra1 100,{
brasilis,155,165,3  script  Orientação divina#bra1  858,{
```

What am I doing wrong, anyone knows?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I suspect you're getting hit by locale headaches...

Comment: What happens if you escape the trailing `{`? `{` is a regex metacharacter.

Comment: @BillyONeal, nothing changes when I escape the trailing {... but I'll add it anyways, didn't know it was a regex metacharacter.

Comment: @BillyONeal It is possible... the file I am opening uses Windows-1252 (ANSI) character set, and when I try to specify a character like "ç" or "á", the regex doesn't work. But the problem is that even without these characters, the regex is still not working. If I change the two `.+` to `[a-fA-F0-9_ ]` it works, but I need to add support for other characters, and doing `[a-fA-F0-9_áÁàÀâÂãÃéÉíÍóÓôÔúÚüÜçÇ ]` is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem come from your first `(.+)` which is greedy and grab all he can, probably until the last `#` of the subject string.

You can try with this pattern:

```
const char *scriptRegexFullNameReplace = "$1\"$2\"#\"$3\"$4";

scriptRegexFullName.assign("(\\p{L}+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+\\s+script\\s+)([^#]+)#(\\S+)(\\s+\\d+,\\{)");
```

Notices:

- the escape of the curly bracket is probably uneeded, try to remove it.
- `p{L}` stand for any unicode letter but you can try replace it by `[^,]` if it is a problem
- You can replace all `+` by `++` for more performances (no backtracks allowed)
- No need to capture the sharp to replace it by itself, it is the reason why the pattern has only four capturing groups
- instead of using `(.+?)` (the dot with a lazy quantifier), it is better for performances to use a greedy quantifier with a reduced character class: `[^#]` that will match all characters until the first `#`

Comment: This was my first thought, but because there are non-optional characters later in the regex I couldn't figure out how matched if the `+` was too greedy, I didn't go that route. Nice work.

Comment: Following your advices I ended up with this: `(\\w++,\\d++,\\d++,\\d++\tscript\t)([^#]++)#([^\t]++)(\t\\d++(,\\d++)?(,\\d++)?,{)` (the \t's are part of the terrible old language I'm working on, so they need to stay there). It worked flawlessly. I didn't think about using [^#], that's a great idea.

Thanks for the help, I learned some good things about regex with your answer.